# How comfortable are users with sharing their numbers with mobile apps?

Tags: users, experience, customer-experience

There are applications which request the user to share their mobile numbers for various reasons(like  for authentication, OTPs and so on).Are the users comfortable with sharing their numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of context missing here.

The answer to the question depends on lot of different factors.

**1. What does the app do ?**

**2. Is it really important for the user ?**

**3. Is asking the number a necessity ?**

**4. If it's not a necessity are there alternatives where you need not provide so much details?**

**5. What kind of audience use the application ?**

If the app is something that the user requires  , the chances of user providing the phone number is high. *Not many people will say no if Facebook or Twitter asks for phone number*.

On the other hand , some random website where you read some tech articles ask for phone number the chances of user declining it will be higher.

*Depends on the necessity of user*.

Many people like privacy in whatever they are doing over the web. If there are options to choose such people will always go for much private apps provided both have similar performance.

**Security Factor**

From a reputed app , if the purpose of asking is authentication , or as backup for changing password ( where the end result is higher security ) user might not hesitate to provide the phone number.

On the other hand ,if the user knows that his phone number will be used for sending loads of annoying text messages he will decline.

Comment: I was thinking for social apps like facebook and twitter or or other apps which send one time passwords for authentication.

Comment: If it's a different app , one first hand why would user want to have a third party app doing the authentication for them ?

Comment: I meant  an app which gives the option of authenticating the user by sending an otp to their number instead of their email ids.

Comment: Yes , in that case providing phone numbers would not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

That depends in how this info will be used.

If it will bring more security to the user, i guess there's not much resistance. But you need to make it clear why you need his number so he'll be confortable/feel safe to give you his info. :)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking apps which ask numbers to send otp for authentication.

Comment: @Vin, so i guess that's ok, it's really common these days to ask for authentication, so it feels natural to the user to allow the use of his number for it. :)